# Incorrect result Kstream-Kstream Join with asymmetric time window

Tags: apache-kafka, left-join, apache-kafka-streams

I have 2 streams named "alarm" and "intervention" that contain JSON. If an alarm and an intervention are connected then they will have the same key. I want to reach them to detect all alarms that haven't had intervention 24 hours before.
But this program doesn't work and gives me as a result all the alarms as if no intervention had been done 24 hours before.
I rechecked my dataset 5 times and there are alarms that have interventions done less than 24 hours before the date of the alarm.
This picture explain the situation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLc60.jpg)
So i need to know if there is an intervention before an alarm.
The code of the program:

```
    final KStream<String, JsonNode> alarm = ...;

    final KStream<String, JsonNode> intervention = ...;

    final JoinWindows jw = JoinWindows.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24)).before(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24)).after(0);

    final KStream<String, JsonNode> joinedAI = alarm.filter((String key, JsonNode value) -> {
        return value != null;
    }).leftJoin(intervention, (JsonNode leftValue, JsonNode rightValue) -> {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = null;

        if (rightValue == null) {//No intervention before
            try {
                actualObj = mapper.readTree("{\"date\":\"" + leftValue.get("date").asText() + "\","
                        + "\"alarm\":" + leftValue.toString()
                        + "}");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            return actualObj;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }, jw, Joined.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde, jsonSerde));

    final KStream<String, JsonNode> fraude = joinedAI.filter((String key, JsonNode value) -> {
        return value != null;
    });

    fraude.foreach((key, value) -> {
        rl.println("Fraude=" + key + " => " + value);
        System.out.println("Fraude=" + key + " => " + value);
    });

    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamingConfig);

    streams.cleanUp();
    streams.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            streams.close();
            rl.close();
            el.close();
            nfl.close();
        }
    }));
```

To sum up, I want to detect the pattern in the red rectangle [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YhAd.jpg)

P.S: I make sure that the intervention records are send before alarm records

Comment: This blog post might help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/ -- joins in Kafka Streams have slightly different semantics that SQL joins.

Answer (score 1):

M.Djx,

I don't think there's a perfect solution for this use case in Kafka Streams right now, but I have a few thoughts to get you closer. I'm preparing to submit a KIP to address exactly use cases like this in the near future.

One point: unlike a KTable, KStreams are not changelogs, so newer events don't overwrite older events with the same key; they just all coexist in the same stream. I think that's why your `foreach` makes it look like all the alerts have no intervention; you're seeing the intermediate join events from before the interventions.

For example:

```
LEFT   RIGHT    JOIN
a:1             a:(1,null)
       a:X      a:(1,X)
```

`foreach` will be invoked on both join results, making it look like the right value is missing, when it's actually just a little late.

If you apply a time-window on the result stream, you *will* get a changelog--newer values will overwrite older ones. Something like:

```
joinedAI
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(
      TimeWindows
          .of(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) // the window will be 24 hours in size
          .until(1000 * 60 * 60 * 48) // and we'll keep it in the state store for at least 48 hours
  ).reduce(
      new Reducer<JsonNode>() {
          @Override
          public Long apply(final JsonNode value1, final JsonNode value2) {
              return value2;
          }
      },
      Materialized.<String, JsonNode, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("alerts-without-interventions")
  );
```

The bummer is that this will produce a changelog stream with the right semantics, but you'll still see the intermediate values, so you wouldn't want to trigger any actions directly from this stream either (like the `foreach`).

One thing you could do is schedule a job, once a day, to scan `"alerts-without-interventions"` for windows from *yesterday*. Any result you get from the window store will be the most recent value from that key.

The KIP I'm preparing will propose a way to let you filter out the intermediate results from the window, which would let you attach a foreach to the changelog and have it trigger only on the final result of the window.

Alternatively, if the data for your app isn't too big, and if you're not too worried about edge cases, you could consider implementing the "window final events" semantics yourself with a LinkedHashMap or a Guava cache.

I hope this helps.